# How to add double quotes in data binding value in angularjs directive?

Tags: angularjs

I am using angularjs directive and I want to add double quotes for a value which is get through data binding in angularjs template.

my code is,

```
template = '<div>'+
            '<a>'+'User name is ' + user.name  + '</a>'+
            '</div>'
```

I need the output as given below
User name is "davit"

How to add double quotes for the name davit?

Answer (score 1):

just add the double quotes before and after single quotes like this

```
'<a>'+'User name is "' + user.name  + '"</a>'+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
template = '<div>'+ '<a>'+'User name is "' + user.name  + '"</a>'+ '</div>'
```